# Character at the end in the INPUT

Tags: html, css

I want to do it as well as in this example in HTML and put the character at the end of the input field. How to do it? Thank you.

[image: inputfield with character]

Comment: Please share your code. What HTML object are you trying this on?

Comment: oh you mean the asterisk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, a working example using position relative:

```css
.required{
  position:relative;
  right:15px;
  top: 3px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" name="full_name"><span class="required">*</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be better and easy

```css
.star {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  margin: -20px 185px;
}
```

```html
<input style="width:200px">
<span class="star">*</span>
```